# Working with ng-if in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-directive

I am new to angular2 (and angular in general). I noticed the **ng-if** directive. Although, I don't seem to be able to get it to work.

Please see the following template code

```
<div ng-if="false">
  This message should not be shown
</div>
```

Although the message still shows. I tried **ng-if={false}** as well but still no luck.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Read here https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Comment: When you choose the documentation to read/learn, choose Angular and skip AngularJS, if you are counting to learn Angular

Comment: Yes, that was the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be *ngIf, try this:

```
<div *ngIf="false">
  This message should not be shown
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! I just noticed that *ngIf works. Could you explain the difference between ng-if and *ngIf. Or point me to any documentation which explains it?

Comment: it's just the way to represent structural directives in angular 2, just to make them easier to recognize [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives) you can accept the answer if that solves your issue!

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is wrong , use *ngIf instead of ng-if, it will work